# Airflow Controller triggers Target DAG with a future execution date; Target DAG stalls

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a Controller DAG (SampleController) that will call a Target DAG (SampleWait), both with a start_date of datetime.now() and a schedule_interval of None.

I trigger the Controller DAG from command line or the webserver UI, and it will run right away with an execution date of "right now" in my system time zone. In the screenshot, it is 17:25 - which isn't my "real" UTC time; it is my local time.

However, when the triggered DAG Run for the target is created, the execution date is "adjusted" to the UTC time, regardless of how I try to manipulate the start_date - it will ALWAYS be in the future (21:25 here). In my case, it is four hours in the future, so the target DAG just sits there doing nothing. I actually have a sensor in the Controller that waits for the Target DAG to finish, so that guy is going to be polling for no reason too.

Even the examples in the Github for the Controller-Target pattern exhibit the exact same behavior when I run them and I can't find any proper documentation on how to *actually* handle this issue, just that it is a "pitfall".

It is strange that Airflow seems to be aware of my time zone and adjusts within one operator, but not when I do it from command line or the web server UI.

What gives?

[image: Target DAG execution date is pushed]

Comment: There are many places (blogs, SO, etc) where it is not recommended to use a "dynamic" datetime.now() date for DAG start dates (think about when DAG code is run and how its used).
As a best practice, you may want to not use naive datetime objects, and always set the tzinfo, probably best to use utc unless you are doing some localized display.

If you provide more info about your usecase, I might be able to make a recommendation on how to proceed, but here is based on assumption:  set start date to past. set schedule_interval=None

Comment: @Nick, I was able to figure this out and moved away from the datetime.now(). essentially, i had a polling ExternalTaskSensor that was blocking (not using Celery executor on my testing) and it had a higher priority weight sum than the other task I wanted to fire off first. 

thanks for the guidance!

Comment: great news!  maybe you can answer / delete the question and close this out?